# Unhandled promise rejection but using .catch()

Tags: javascript, node.js

When call a `throw` from async function node says an error:

> Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an `async` function without a `catch` block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with `.catch()`.

But i have a `.catch()` defined on call:

```js
class Cls {
    async fn(){
        throw new Error('err');
        return 'test';
    }
}

cls = new Cls();
cls.fn()
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch(e => { throw e })
```

What is the problem?

Comment: You just rethrow it in your catch.. Who's catching it this time?

Comment: But need execute `.catch()` to avoid use try catch. I use `express` and global error handling for responses but can not execute the `catch()`.

Comment: Oohh really execute `catch()`. What is the error message? but native error require.

Comment: There's no `.catch()` AFTER you do `throw e` in the existing `.catch()` so that rejection is unhandled.  Remember that `.catch()` returns another promise and that promise will fulfill or reject.

Answer (score 2):

The catch here

```js
cls.fn()
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch(e => { throw e })
```

is actually catching an error thrown inside the fn method.:

```js
  throw new Error('err');
```

However, after you catch it, you explicitly raise another error

```js
.catch(e => { throw e });
```

And now there's no one to capture this new error you throw, so your program crashes.